# Getting java.lang.noclassdeffounderror org/codehaus/jackson/map/objectmapper error.

Tags: java, jackson

I am using Jackson 2.5.4 and the Objectmapper class should be available in com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper. But for some reason it requires the org.codehaus.jackson.map.Objectmapper class which was used by Jackson 1.x . 
I am trying to update the jar to from Jackson 1.x to 2.x but I am not able to figure out why it requires the old jar even though I am not using it anymore.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add how did you define the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

2 things to check:

1. See if you forgot an import at one of your files. Make sure you import from `com.fasterxml` everywhere:

   ```
   import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
   ```

   A full text search for the string `"org.codehaus.jackson"` in all `*.java` files will help.
2. Run `mvn dependency:tree` or the equivalent in whatever build system you use. That would show you how the dependency to the older Jackson ends up in your jar (e.g. as transitive dependency)